# Totcount: registering multiple auxiliary files

Tags: totcount

According to the totcount guide, I can define multiple auxiliary files within the same document, by using different \regtotcounter[auxfile=]{} commands.
I want to do that because I want to keep different total counters in different files.
However, as the following simple example shows, only the last-defined auxiliary file will contain the values of all total counters registered.
Is this a bug in totcount's code?

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter[auxfile=eqscount.tc]{equation}
\regtotcounter[auxfile=figscount.tc]{figure}


\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
a=b\label{eq:e1}
\end{equation}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
c=d\label{eq:2}
\end{equation}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{figure}

\caption{Fig. \label{fig:1}}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: looks like a bug. But you really don't want to use this option. The package allocates for each one a new write register and keeps it open. write registers are scarce resources and this is wasting them for no use at all.

Comment: How so?  I intend to load and use these total counters in other documents.